# How do I rectify error with AVD GPU issue ( invalid GPU mode angle9 )?

Tags: java, android, sdk, gpu, android-virtual-device

I cannot seem to rectify by reinstalling the emulator or even reinstalling android studio .

I have tried to click on menu for the Virtual device but the screen shows an error message.

12:35 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect

12:35 PM    Emulator: emuglConfig_init: Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect

12:35 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

12:35 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

12:36 PM    Emulator: emuglConfig_init: Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect

12:36 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader swiftshader_indirect

12:36 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

12:36 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZKIK.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and finally solved it by starting the emulator from commmand prompt with with option -gpu host:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_29 -gpu host
```

If you don't remember the name of the avd, you can list them with:

```
> emulator -list-avd
Pixel_3a_API_29
```

If you don't have the emulator.exe on path, you can add it with:

```
set PATH=%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%PATH%
```

Comment: The command to list avds was supposed to be "emulator -list-avds" not -list-avd.